How to hide Laravel Filament table filters modal popup
I am working with Filament Table in a Laravel project. I want to hide the filters modal when the "Apply Filters" button is clicked. Here is the code I'm currently working with. How can I achieve this functionality?

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table->deferLoading()->recordUrl(null)->paginated([10, 25, 50, 75, 100])->striped()
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('#')->rowIndex(),
                TextColumn::make('name')->searchable()
                ->sortable(),
                TextColumn::make('contact_number')->label('Contact Number')->searchable()
                ->sortable(),
                TextColumn::make('email')->searchable()
                ->sortable(),
                ImageColumn::make('company_logo')->height(50),
                TextColumn::make('status')->badge()->searchable()
                ->color(fn (string $state): string => match ($state) {
                    Status::Active->value => Status::Active->getColor(),
                    Status::Deactive->value => Status::Deactive->getColor(),
                    default => 'gray', 
                })
                ->formatStateUsing(fn (string $state): string => match ($state) {
                    Status::Active->value => Status::Active->getLabel(),
                    Status::Deactive->value => Status::Deactive->getLabel(),
                    default => 'Unknown', 
                })
                ->icon(fn (string $state): ?string => match ($state) {
                    Status::Active->value => Status::Active->getIcon(),
                    Status::Deactive->value => Status::Deactive->getIcon(),
                    default => null, 
                })
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
            ])
            ->defaultSort('id', 'desc')
            ->filters(static::getTableFilters())
            ->filtersTriggerAction(
                fn (Action $action) => $action
                    ->button()
                    ->label('Filters')
            )
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])->deferFilters();
    }

You can see this image. I want to hide the filters modal when the Filters is applied
any one help me on this i am stuck on this.

